# compare values of data frames with different number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, row, string-comparison

I defined the following function, which takes two DataFrames, DF_TAGS_LIST and DF_epc_list. Both data frames have a column with a different number of rows. I want to search each value DF_TAGS_LIST in DF_epc_list, and if found, store it in another dataframe

One example of DF_TAGS_LIST:

```
TAGS_LIST
3036029B539869100000000B
3036029B537663000000002A
3036029B5398694000000009
3036029B539869400000000C
3036029B5398690000000006
3036029B5398692000000007
```

And one example of DF_epc_list:

```
EPC
3036029B539869100000000B
3036029B537663000000002A
3036029B5398690000000006
3036029B5398692000000007
3036029B5398691000000006
3036029B5376630000000034
3036029B53986940000000WF
3036029B5398694000000454
3036029B5398690000000234
3036029B53986920000000FG
```

In this case, I would like one dataframe output that had the following values:

```
FOUND_TAGS
3036029B5398690000000006
3036029B5398692000000007
3036029B539869100000000B
3036029B537663000000002A
```

My function is:

```
FOUND_COMPARE_TAGS<-function(DF_TAGS_LIST, DF_epc_list){
  DF_epc_list<-toString(DF_epc_list)
  DF_TAGS_LIST<-toString(DF_TAGS_LIST)
  DF_found_epc_tags <- data.frame(DF_found_epc_tags=intersect(DF_TAGS_LIST$DF_TAGS_LIST, DF_epc_list$DF_epc_list)); setdiff(union(DF_TAGS_LIST$DF_TAGS_LIST, DF_epc_list$DF_epc_list), DF_found_epc_tags$DF_found_epc_tags)
  #DF_found_epc_tags <- data.frame(DF_found_epc_tags = DF_TAGS_LIST[unique(na.omit(match(DF_epc_list$DF_epc_list, DF_TAGS_LIST$DF_TAGS_LIST))),])
  return(DF_found_epc_tags)
}
```

I now returns an empty data frame with two columns. Only recently programmed in R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `%in%` or (as I mentioned in my comment) `intersect`:

```
DF_TAGS_LIST[DF_TAGS_LIST$TAGS_LIST %in% DF_epc_list$EPC, , drop = FALSE]
#                  TAGS_LIST
# 1 3036029B539869100000000B
# 2 3036029B537663000000002A
# 5 3036029B5398690000000006
# 6 3036029B5398692000000007
intersect(DF_TAGS_LIST$TAGS_LIST, DF_epc_list$EPC)
# [1] "3036029B539869100000000B" "3036029B537663000000002A" 
# [3] "3036029B5398690000000006" "3036029B5398692000000007"
```

Comment: The difference is that `intersect` is a set operation and by default returns intersecting results with no duplicates.

Comment: @Arun, Yes. I'm actually just now re-reading their attempted solution to see if I have a better understanding of what they're actually looking for as the result. I see that `intersect` is already in their present function.

Comment: Basically, I want to find the values ​​of DF_TAGS_LIST in  DF_TAGS_LIST, and when I find a match, I want to save that value in another data frame.

Comment: @Alex, then I would just use `%in%`. By default, that will give you a logical vector. Use that to subset from your source vector and add that to your other `data.frame`.

Comment: FOUND_COMPARE_TAGS<-function(DF_TAGS_LIST, DF_epc_list){
  DF_Found_TAGS<-intersect(DF_TAGS_LIST[,1], DF_epc_list[,1])
  DF_Found_TAGS<-as.data.frame(DF_Found_TAGS)
  return(DF_Found_TAGS)
}´

Answer (score 0):

```
FOUND_TAGS <- rbind(TAGS_LIST, EPC) 
FOUND_TAGS <- FOUND_TAGS[duplicated(FOUND_TAGS), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Wwhen I use this code I get this error: 
Error in match.names (cLabs, names (xi)): 
   names do not match previous names 
Called from: match.names (cLabs, names (xi))